# Debug Firefox Sidebar in Firebug?

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox, dom, sidebar

I have a web application that works fine in the main window of Firefox but there are certain jquery or bootstrap or unknown issues when that same URL is loaded into a Firefox sidebar. Namely, some CSS elements don't appear (glyphicons). They work fine when the URL is loaded into a main window.

Is there anyway to get Firebug or some other debugging tool to inspect the sidebar as if it was the main window?

Thanks

Comment: Yes in sidebar right click there will be inspect Element(Q) there you can check your styles

Comment: or else in Chrome there will be default developer tools when you click f12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a good answer and ended up not relying on cookies in the sidebar.